Unable to Load Phi3 Model in open-webui through WSL and Docker
I want to run the phi3 model locally on my laptop using WSL, Ollama, Docker, and Open-webui. Here are the steps I have followed:
Installed WSL.
Installed Ollama.
Pulled the phi3 model using Ollama.
Installed Docker.
Installed Open-webui.
I can chat with the model via the terminal. However, when I set up open-webui and try to select the model, it does not appear in the model list.
I have checked the following and the model still didn't show up in the list:

The model phi3 is listed and works correctly in the terminal.
Docker is running correctly.
I have restarted Docker and open-webui services.

Checking the logs, I found this:
2024-05-31 11:05:31 INFO:apps.ollama.main:get_all_models()
2024-05-31 11:05:31 ERROR:apps.ollama.main:Connection error: Cannot connect to host host.docker.internal:11434 ssl:default [Connection refused]

How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

I had a similar issue having followed some tutorial but then I ended up on the Open-WebUI page and using the command from there worked:
docker run -d --network=host -v open-webui:/app/backend/data -e OLLAMA_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:11434 --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main

Note that the port changes from 3000 to 8080 so you will need to use http://localhost:8080.
